# Android - How to layout buttons inside image?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have some image with areas. I would like to react on click in specific area, but I can't cut this image into separate images. You can see example below.

[image: Example image]

Black circles are my areas. Red rectangles are my transparent buttons. How would you implement this in XML ? I want to make sure that active buttons will always cover the same area in background image.

I've tried to do this using FrameLayout :

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/_podklad" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:contentDescription="prawy_tyl"
                    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@null"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:contentDescription="lewe_kolo_przod"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@null"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:contentDescription="lewe_kolo_tyl"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@null"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:contentDescription="prawe_kolo_przod"
                    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@null"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:contentDescription="prawe_kolo_tyl"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@null"/>
            </RelativeLayout></FrameLayout>
```

As you can see I tried to specify fixed width, height and margins for buttons, but in Android studio it worked well on Nexus 4 preview, but on larger screen like Nexus 9 the buttons were misplaced.

I wait for your ideas.

Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you know your image and you know where the areas located in this image in pixels i don't recommend using transparent buttons 
you can instead use (`onTouchListener`) for this Image and as response to this touch first do `View.measure` to this Image and then do your mapping depending on the (x,y) axis

Comment: I've implemented it using `onTouchListener` as you said :) Now I don't need to worry about buttons misplacements. Thank you for inspiration ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add circle in image, and change the attributes of padding = 10dp or padding 20dp.
or padding-left or padding - right